# is this sentence correct "In addition to the above, for the last one year, I have also been serving as DNO of Bishnupur District."

Tags: recurring-events

"In addition to the above, for the last one year, I have also been serving as DNO of Bishnupur District."

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from the crafting of this sentence that this is part of a résumé. Be that as it may, the "one" in "last one year" is redundant, as "year" is singular, already implying only one. Otherwise, the sentence is grammatically correct as "In addition to the above, for the last year I have also been serving as DNO of [the?] Bishnupur District."

Comment: the main thing i would like to know is the use of Adverb i.e. also........I have also been serving....is this correct to say so ?...or it should be..I have been also serving as....?

Comment: "I have also been serving" is OK. In American English, we would say "**the** Bishnupur District," but if that is not how you would say it locally, then not using the article "the" is OK as well. Good luck!

Comment: According to the Chicago Manual of Style, either placement of the word "also" is correct. As long as it follows the first auxiliary verb "have," it is acceptable. As for the edit to my original answer--the insertion of the "the" before Bishnupur District--I'm going to have to disagree. It would be equivalent to saying "I have been Attorney General for *the* New York State." Only if the word order were reversed--"the State of New York"--would the article be either necessary or correct.